# Applications in subfolder in 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have a projectfolder structure like this:

```
project
    applications
        __init__.py
        app1
        app2
        app3
    project
        __init__.py
        settings.py
```

In my settings.py Im trying to import the apps like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...

    'applications.app1',
    'applications.app2',
    'applications.app3',
)
```

But if I try to migrate one of the app, I get this error:

```
./manage.py makemigrations applications.app1
App 'applications.app1' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
```

What could be wrong? This kind of setup used to work with django 1.6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the applications folder on your `PYTHONPATH`?

You could add it in the settings file by putting this underneath `BASE_DIR`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("applications"))
```

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a Django-native solution to this. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#app-names):

> Many commands take a list of “app names.” An “app name” is the basename of the package containing your models. For example, if your INSTALLED_APPS contains the string 'mysite.blog', the app name is blog.